# Is it possible to access the MS Windows certificate template name of an X509 certificate from Java?

Tags: java, windows, ssl, active-directory, x509certificate

Using [BouncyCastle library](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) and the code below it is possible to access the MS Windows certificate template information extension of a SSL certificate stored in MS Windows' trust/certificate store.

```
final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-My", "SunMSCAPI");
keyStore.load(null, null);
final X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
// see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/supported-extensions#template
final String XCN_OID_CERTIFICATE_TEMPLATE = "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7";
final byte[] extensionValue = certificate.getExtensionValue(XCN_OID_CERTIFICATE_TEMPLATE);
final ASN1InputStream aIn = new ASN1InputStream(extensionValue);
ASN1Primitive asn1obj = aIn.readObject();

if (asn1obj instanceof DEROctetString)
{
   final DEROctetString octets = (DEROctetString) asn1obj;
   asn1obj = ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(octets.getOctets());
 }
final ASN1Sequence asn1seq = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(asn1obj);
final ASN1Encodable obj1 = asn1seq.getObjectAt(0);

final ASN1Primitive certificateTemplateOID = obj1.toASN1Primitive();
System.out.println(certificateTemplateOID.toString());
```

It will print out something like 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.... which is the OID of the certificate template.

Now I would like to know if there is a Java method or Java library which provides a mapping of this OID to the certificate template name (as a user-friendly string) - like it is done when you click on details of a certificate in Windows certificiate store:
[Certificate template information in MS Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7DBP.jpg)

Additional links:

- [Windows certificate extension for certificate templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/supported-extensions#template)
- [Windows certificate extension for certificate templates - data structure](https://www.pkisolutions.com/object-identifiers-oid-in-pki/)
- [ObjectIdentifiers (OID) in PKI](https://www.pkisolutions.com/object-identifiers-oid-in-pki/)

Answer (score 0):

the only way to get mapping for this OID value is to call <s>[CryptEnumOIDInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptenumoidinfo)</s> function on a domain-joined machine. These OIDs are generated dynamically and stored in Active Directory. This function can read OIDs from local OID database and from Active Directory. Note, that you must call this function in AD forest where that certificate template is installed.

---

**17.02.2021 update:**
I specified wrong function. Actual function is [CryptFindOIDInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptfindoidinfo). The function accepts three parameters with the following values (for your given case):

- `dwKeyType` -- must be 1 (`CRYPT_OID_INFO_OID_KEY`)
- `*pvKey` -- must be a pointer to an ANSI string.
- `dwGroupId` -- must be 9 (`CRYPT_TEMPLATE_OID_GROUP_ID`)

the function returns a pointer to a [CRYPT_OID_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/ns-wincrypt-crypt_oid_info) structure. `pwszName` will store friendly name of the requested OID. In a given case, union value of `CRYPT_OID_INFO` structure is `DWORD  dwValue`. I have no idea how easy this is in Java.

As another option, if you can access .NET API from Java, you can try instantiating an [Oid class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.oid) using `Oid(String)` constructor:

```
var oid = new System.Security.Cryptography.Oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8...");
Console.WriteLine(oid.FriendlyName); // this will output template display name.
```

Comment: What do you mean by calling this function in AD forest...? Do I have to provide a certain parameter to the function or do I have to call an additional function first when using [JavaNativeAccess](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)

Comment: `in AD forest` -- the function must be called on a machine that is joined to AD forest where this particular template exist. Check updated response, I originally mistyped proper function name.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Crypt32, the function [CryptFindOIDInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptfindoidinfo) has to be called via [Java NativeAccess (JNA)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna):

Here is the code for JNA Version 4.1.0:

```
final NativeLibrary crypt32 = NativeLibrary.getInstance("Crypt32");
final int CRYPT_OID_INFO_OID_KEY = 1;
final int XCN_CRYPT_TEMPLATE_OID_GROUP_ID = 9;
final Function functionCryptFindOIDInfo = crypt32.getFunction("CryptFindOIDInfo");
final String ptrPvKey = certificateTemplateOID.toString();

final Object[] argsCryptFindOIDInfo = new Object[] { CRYPT_OID_INFO_OID_KEY, ptrPvKey,
        XCN_CRYPT_TEMPLATE_OID_GROUP_ID };
final CRYPT_OID_INFO result = (CRYPT_OID_INFO) functionCryptFindOIDInfo.invoke(CRYPT_OID_INFO.class,
        argsCryptFindOIDInfo);
System.out.println(result.pwszName);
```

class CRYPT_OID_INFO.java

```
public class CRYPT_OID_INFO extends Structure
{
  public int cbSize;
  public String pszOID;
  public WString pwszName;
  public int dwGroupId;
  public DUMMYUNION DUMMYUNIONNAME;

  public CRYPT_DATA_BLOB ExtraInfo;
  public String pwszCNGAlgid;
  public String pwszCNGExtraAlgid;


  @Override
  public List<String> getFieldOrder()
  {
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add("cbSize");
    result.add("pszOID");
    result.add("pwszName");
    result.add("dwGroupId");
    result.add("DUMMYUNIONNAME");
    result.add("ExtraInfo");
    result.add("pwszCNGAlgid");
    result.add("pwszCNGExtraAlgid");
    return result;
  }
}
```

class DUMMYUNION .java

```
public class DUMMYUNION extends Union
{
  public int dwValue;
  public int Algid;
  public int dwLength;
}
```

class CRYPT_DATA_BLOB

```
public class CRYPT_DATA_BLOB extends Structure
{
  public int cbData;
  public Pointer pbData;

  @Override
  public List<String> getFieldOrder()
  {
    final String[] array = new String[] { "cbData", "pbData" };
    return Arrays.asList(array);
  }
}
```